# Easy example of a stable pair in the sense of Hitchin

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface with metric $g=hdzd{\overline{z}}$ compatible with the conformal structure.
Then

1. The Levi-Civita connection is a $U(1)$ connection defined on the canonical bundle $K$. How to see that?
2. Let $K^{1/2}$ denote a holomorphic lin bundle such that $K^{1/2}\otimes K^{1/2}\cong K$ with the induced $U(1)$ connection. How can we check the existence of $K^{1/2}$?
3. Let P be the principal $SU(2)$ bundle associated to $V=K^{1/2}\oplus K^{-1/2}$. With respect to this decomposition of $V$, define $\Phi\in \Omega^{1,0}(ad(P)\otimes \Bbb C)$ by
   $\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0\\
   1 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}$. Then the pair $(V,\Phi)$ is stable (in the sense of [Hitchin](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/plms/s3-55.1.59)), i.e,  for every $\Phi$-invariant  rank-$1$ subbundle  $L$  of $V$,$\operatorname{deg}L < \operatorname{deg}(\Lambda^2V)$. This is obvious from the definition if we can prove that $K^{-1/2}$ is the only $\Phi$-invariant subbundle. How can we see that?

Thank you for any help or reference in the right direction.

Comment: For 3. I can see why $K^{-1/2}$ is a $\Phi$-invariant subbundle but I can't see why it is the only one.

Comment: HINT: Because $c_1(K) = 2g-2 = 2(g-1)$ is even, there is a holomorphic line bundle with $c_1 = g-1$. (From the exponential sequence, we know that $H^1(M,\mathscr O^*) \to H^2(M,\Bbb Z)$ is surjective.) For your first question, note that a connection on $E$ canonically gives an associated connection on $E^*$, and $K = T^*M$.